# Is there "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" like Properties for CheckedListBox control? C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, checkedlistbox

I have this `DataTable` with the following structure:

```
ID | VALUE
----------------
1  | Item 1
2  | Item 2
3  | Item 3
```

And I display the values from the `DataTable` into a `CheckedListBox` control by adding each row as an item.

But how can I include the ID? 
Is there "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" like Properties for CheckedListBox control?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well yes, there are `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties on `CheckedListBox`, although the docs for [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb(v=VS.90).aspx) claim it's "not relevant to this class".

Here's a quick example showing `DisplayMember` working:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CheckedListBox clb = new CheckedListBox {
            DisplayMember = "Foo",
            ValueMember = "Bar",
            Items = {
                new { Foo = "Hello", Bar = 10 },
                new { Foo = "There", Bar = 20 }
            }
        };
        Form f = new Form
        {
            Controls = { clb }
        };
        Application.Run(f);
    }
}
```

Also note that the docs state:

> You cannot bind data to a CheckedListBox. Use a ComboBox or a ListBox for this instead. 
>   For more information, see How to: Bind a Windows Forms ComboBox or ListBox Control to Data.

Given the above code which works, presumably it's talking about more advanced data binding, using `DataSource`?

Comment: I did not see any sir for DisplayMember and ValueMember properties on CheckedListBox.

Comment: @yonan2236: Well they're there... IntelliSense or the designer may not suggest them, but they exist.

Comment: thank you very much sir. (Mr. Jon Skeet answered my question, I feel very lucky today.)

Comment: it's working sir Jon, I will try to use other DataSource. Thanks again :)

Comment: sir can I ask again a question?

Comment: For some reason DisplayMember, DataSource, DrawMode and ItemHeight are hidden properties of CheckedListBox. You can use them, but Intellisense and the Object Browser will not display them if hidden items aren't being displayed (which they usually aren't).

Comment: `DisplayMember` seems to work if you assign it after `DataSource`, but not before. Therefore it would have no effect if set in the properties window. This is probably the cause, why the property is hidden.

Answer (score 8):

The DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember properties are available for this control but they are not displayed in the IntelliSense: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.datasource%28VS.90%29.aspx)

You should be able to use them though.

Comment: Wow, why is this not displayed in Intellisense? That's extremely confusing.

Comment: Ok, because the BrowsableAttribute on those properties has a value of false.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are 'display member' and 'value member' properties in CheckedListBox.

You can set the properties as you do in combobox:

```
   public void PopulateListBox(System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox lb, string displayMember, string valueMember, DataTable data)
   {
        lb.DataSource = data; // where data is the datatable. datatable filled up with //data fetched from database.
        lb.ValueMember = valueMember;
        lb.DisplayMember = displayMember;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[The french documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/3yx132k0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) say : Cette propriété ne s'applique pas à cette classe.
"This property does not apply for this class".
This little line of text is not visible in the us documentation...