# How will I get the SelectedItem? C# winforms CheckedListBox control

Tags: c#

Prior to this question, I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801290/is-there-displaymember-and-valuemember-like-properties-for-checkedlistbox-con) question on this site. (Mr Jon Skeet answered it!)

I'm having difficulty retrieving the `SelectedItem` of the `CheckedListBox`.
Please consider my code:

```
public class StaticValues
{
    private string value;
    private string display;
    public StaticValues(string val, string disp)
    {
        this.value = val;
        this.display = disp;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        { return value; }
    }

    public string Display
    {
        get
        { return display; }
    }
}

private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList dataSource = new ArrayList();
    dataSource.Add(new StaticValues("001", "Item 1"));
    dataSource.Add(new StaticValues("002", "Item 2"));
    dataSource.Add(new StaticValues("003", "Item 3"));
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
    checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); // outputs correct SelectedValue 
    MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); // this one doesn't for SelectedItem
}
```

How will I get the `SelectedItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it's a list of check boxes, I suspect it would be better to find *all* the checked items using the [`CheckedListBox.CheckedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkedindices.aspx) property. From there, you can get to the individual item and find the appropriate value from it. While `DisplayMember` works, I suspect you're better off casting the item to the known type and finding the value that way, unless that's really awkward for you. There may be another way round it, but I don't know of one. Note that the docs for [`CheckedListBox.ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.valuemember%28VS.90%29.aspx) claim that it's "not relevant to this class".

Comment: @yonan2236: Could you give more details?

Comment: I just can't get the selected item sir when i use datasource. Base from my code above. MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

Comment: @yonan2236: But I didn't suggest using SelectedItem. I suggested using CheckedIndices. I assumed that's what you meant by "I can't make it work".

Comment: this is the output when i use checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(): "MyClass.Form3+StaticValues"

Comment: @yonan2236: Well in that case it's easy: just cast SelectedItem to `StaticValues` and get the property that way. But as I *keep* saying, I suggest you use CheckedIndices anyway, because there may be more than one checked item.

Comment: Sir what do you mean by "just cast SelectedItem to StaticValues and get the property that way"?

Comment: @yonan2236 like this: `StaticValues staticValues = (StaticValues) checkedListBox1.SelectedItem;`

Comment: I got it sir :                                                                StaticValues staticValues = (StaticValues)checkedListBox1.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show(staticValues.Display.ToString());

Comment: @yonan2236: Bear in mind that there could be multiple selected items or none though. I would *strongly* urge you to use CheckedIndices and loop through *all* the checked items.

Answer (score 0):

Initially there is no selected item, at least until a user selects one. 
To retrieve a user selected value you must react to the  wselectedIndexChanged event and if the user changes that value to the OnSelectedValueChanged event.

If you wish to find which items have their checkboxes set then you'll need to look at the CheckecItemCollection and CheckedIndexCollection properties.