# How to get the value of the checkListBox

Tags: c#

I am working on a windows form application and I have a checkListBox that is binded to my database. I am using parameter method to store the selected Text. However, I want to get the primary key of that item similar to `comboBox.SelectedValue` instead of the Text. Are there way to do this?

Here is my code. As you can see, the parameter is filtered by the checkedItem text. When I select my checkedItem from my checkListBox, it suppose to only get the selected items. This work fine if my CheckListBox item has something like Peter, Amy, Bob, and David (non duplicate name). However, if my checkListBox has duplicate name. Peter, Amy, Amy, Bob, David, Amy,this will cause problem. If I select the first Amy, My `parameterList` will have Amy, Amy, Amy. This is a problem because I am filtering it by my firstName (so whenever they see the same name, it will add to the `parameterList`. What I really want is to filter by a key such as employeeId so that it will not have any duplicate name in my `parameterList`. (Just like when I change from `comboBox.selecteIndex` to  `comboBox.selectedValue`). When I selected only the the first Amy, my parameterList should only have one checked Amy, but not all the Amy that isn't even checked.  I am wondering if I can do something like `selectedValue` from my comboBox  value` to map the database value? Help will be appreciated

for example here is my checkListBox:

```
[x]Amy
[]Peter
[]David
[]Amy
[]Amy
[]Jimmy
```

You can see only the first Amy is selected. But my parameterList has Amy, Amy, Amy since I am filtering by firstName.

```
    string parameterList = "";
    int parameterCounter = 0;

    // Add a parameter placeholder for each "checked" item
    for (var t = 0; t < employeeCheckListBox.CheckedItems.Count; t++)
    {
        parameterList += (t == 0) ? "@p" + t : ", @p" + t;

    }

    string query = "select distinct firstName, lastName, employeeEmail, 
                           entryYear, leaveYear 
                    from[employee_detail] as ed 
                    LEFT JOIN[department_detail] as dd ON ed.employeeId = dd.employeeId
                    Where firstName = (" + parameterList + ")";

    myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);

    for (var t = 0; t < employeeCheckListBox.CheckedItems.Count; t++)
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@p" + t, employeeCheckListBox.CheckedItems[t].ToString());
    }      
    if (employeeCheckListBox.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
    {    
        myCommand = new SqlCommand(Equery, myConn);
    }
```

Here is what I want to change

```
string query = "select distinct firstName, lastName, employeeEmail, 
                               entryYear, leaveYear 
                        from[employee_detail] as ed 
                        LEFT JOIN[department_detail] as dd ON ed.employeeId = dd.employeeId
                        Where firstName = (" + parameterList + ")";
```

//the parameterList should be the selected value of the checkListBox

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801290/is-there-displaymember-and-valuemember-like-properties-for-checkedlistbox-co) should help you.

Comment: Your question is not making much sense to me.. probably it need editing..

Comment: @AmneshGoel, I have edited my question, see if this make sense

Comment: @DragonBorn join chat room to discuss this issue in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your problem is you have multiple employees with the same name, and
>   how your user will differentiate between them on UI.

So a very easy and quick fix to this problem is, change your content on UI which you are displaying in checkboxlist.

Since each employee will have unique email id... So display EmailID along with Name.. change your query as below..

```
select td.teacherId as ID, chineseName + ' ' + email as Name from[teacher_detail] .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the value member with any ID of the employee record as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875540/how-to-get-value-of-checked-item-from-checkedlistbox) question