# Get CheckedListBox item ValueMember

Tags: c#

I have a `CheckedListBox` which I fill with code:

```
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, new {Text = "text1", Value = "value1" });
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, new {Text = "text2", Value = "value2" });
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, new {Text = "text3", Value = "value3" });

foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
    // ?
}
```

How can I get the `ValueMember`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" like Properties for CheckedListBox control? C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801290/is-there-displaymember-and-valuemember-like-properties-for-checkedlistbox-co)

Comment: Value member is for all items value from binding source etc.. So why r you accessing inside the foreach please specified and agree with @Plutonix duplicate too.

Comment: I also assign value in label from ValueMember using this code
label1.Text = checkedListBox1.ValueMember;

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating anonymous Type here

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, new {Text = "text1", Value = "value1" });
```

you can simply overcome this by creating a new class

```
class NewType
{
   public string Text;
   public  string Value;
}
```

Then your Foreach will look like that

```
foreach (NewType item in checkedListBox1.Items)
        {
            item.value
        }
```